# How to extend classes from other files in Typescript 2.2.2?

Tags: angular, inheritance, typescript

Before you consider my question as duplicate, I already tried everything answered in other questions and no success. Let me explain my problem:

I have an Angular 2 App and an Express API sharing a private package written in Typescript that contains classes for my domain. All of them are using Typescript 2.2.2.

In the priavte package there is a class that extends another class in another file and the project compiles. The problem happens when I try to use the package in my Angular app: everything breaks and the console shows `TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`.

That only happens if the child class is present in the package, otherwise everything works fine.

Ex:

```js
// child/child.ts

import { Parent } from '../parent/parent';

export class Child extends Parent { }
```

```js
// parent/parent.ts
export class Parent {
    foo: string;
}
```

```js
// bar/bar.ts
import { Child } from '../child/child';

export class Bar {
    child: Child;
}
```

In the private package I'm using Gulp to compile Typescript to Javascript and generate the declarations file.

Here is the `.tsconfig` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": false
    },
    "include": [
        "**/**.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Here is the `.gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var merge = require('merge2');
var tsConfig = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { declaration: true });

gulp.task("release", [], () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('src/**/**.ts')
        .pipe(tsConfig());

    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('release/definitions')),
        tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('release/js'))
    ]);
});
```

My files structure:

```
+ root
|
+--+ bar
|  |
|  +-- bar.ts
|
+--+ child
|  |
|  +-- child.ts
|
+--+ parent
   |
   +-- parent.ts
```

I've read that it could be a problem with sorting the classes names when compiling, because Parent has to be compiled before Child. The solution would be writing the directive `/// <reference path="parent/parent">` in my child class, but when I try to compile it fails and says the reference directive doesn't exist. If I write `references` instead of `reference` it compiles, but the resulting js files are the same, except by that extra line, and don't work.

Comment: You don't have a baseUrl specified but you're referencing `import { Child } from 'child/child';`? Is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: But the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

in your `tsconfig` file, you dont have a `baseUrl` so typescript **cannot** resolve this import in `bar/bar.ts`: `import { Child } from 'child/child';`

to resolve this you need to switch your import to the relative path to 'child' file.

IF your directory structure was

```
root
--bar
----bar.ts
--child
----child.ts
```

then your file becomes:

```
// bar/bar.ts
import { Child } from '../child/child'; // <---

export class Bar {
    child: Child;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: But the problem persists